# Who is joining the EuroTeX 2012 in Breskens?

Tags: discussion, conferences

Title tells it all: who is going to this year's EuroTeX?

http://www.ntg.nl/eurotex2012/

(/me is coming)

Comment: I am curious  why we need a face-to-face event, does an  online discussion not suffice?

Comment: @GarbageCollector The best discussions are during the breaks. We show what we are working on during the presentations, during the breaks (and in the evening after some beers) we tell others how we solved problems and what is needed. But the most important thing is: if you join more and more of these conferences, you get to know the people involved very well. Then working together makes much more fun. Some of the people going there I know for more than 10 years and we sometimes meet two or three times a year. I feel a great and warm welcome when I go to a european TeX conference.

Comment: I understood the point. Thank you.

Comment: (/me is coming).

Comment: @GarbageCollector Do you know an online forum which could replace such a meeting? Not TeX.SE for sure, as this is purely Q&A.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: It depends on the objective of the meeting. If the objective is only for discussing technical things that can be accomplished remotely, I don't think we need a face-to-face meeting.

Comment: I'm making a day visit --- I can't come the whole week, but it's close enough to come down for a day, and I definitely want to do that.